# sed command add multiple lines bash

Tags: bash, maven, sed, newline

I am new to bash coding in Linux.I want to add plugin to my existing pom file in maven project.So want to add this plugin.This is the way i changed file.But it failed.

```
sed -i "47 i\<plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>"

" animalNames.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called `plugin.tmp` with this data:

```
<plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then insert it into `animalNames.txt` at line #47:

```
sed -i.bak '47r plugin.tmp' animalNames.txt
```

To create a `plugin.tmp` file:

```
cat << EOF > plugin.tmp
<plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
</plugin>
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks but i can't create file.In the bash script it self i want to change the code.

Comment: I know i can create file file.but my purpose it is not allowed to create files.Is that ok to change <\\plugin\\> like this way.

Comment: You can create a file in `/tmp` directory. Also if you don't have write permissions when how is `sed -i` going to work for you?

Comment: i have done what you have said.But it is not write my plugin code to pom.xml file

Comment: What I have posted here is working code that will work even with older version of sed. Make sure you copy/paste it as is.

Comment: yes i have copy paste these lines.cat << EOF > plugin.tmp
<plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
</plugin>

sed -i.bak '47r plugin.tmp' /home/ubuntu/samples/sampleapp/pom.xml